# Chance of getting sexual transmitted diseases

Tags: disease-transmission, sti, condom, proper-use

What are the chances of getting sexual transmitted diseases (and which) given that:

1. Heterosexual sex
2. Male partner used condom (properly)
3. The condom was NOT damaged during the act

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that we are talking about the risk of having intercourse one time under the conditions you described, and assuming you do not know if your male partner had an STD, and provided your partner used a latex or polyurethane condom labeled as protective against disease, the risk of contracting HIV, gonorrhea, chlamydia, and trichomoniasis quite low (it is **very unlikely** that you contracted any of those STDs), although it is not zero.

The risk of contracting genital ulcer diseases (herpes, syphilis, chancroid) and HPV (human papillomavirus) infections, even with proper condom use, is somewhat higher, although it is **statistically unlikely** that you contracted one of those STDs from one-time intercourse as you described.

Of course, the best advice (which you will see on any authoritative website, journal article, or from your own doctor) is: **"When in doubt, get it checked out."** And in general, regular STD testing is the best way to prevent the spread of STDs (if you know you have an STD, you can either not have sex or inform your partner(s) and take preventative measures) and to treat them early and more effectively if you happen to contract one. Talk with your doctor, a local health clinic, or other health provider about how often you should get tested.

Here is some related information that might be helpful:

[From the FDA](https://www.fda.gov/ForPatients/Illness/HIVAIDS/ucm126372.htm) (United States Food & Drug Administration):

> **Will a condom guarantee I won't get a sexually transmitted infection?**
>
> When used consistently and correctly, condoms are highly effective in
>   preventing HIV. They are also effective at preventing sexually
>   transmitted diseases (STDs) that are transmitted through bodily
>   fluids, such as gonorrhea and chlamydia. However, they provide less
>   protection against STDs spread through skin-to-skin contact like human
>   papillomavirus (genital warts), genital herpes, and syphilis. Although
>   highly effective when used consistently and correctly, there is still
>   a chance of getting HIV if you only use condoms, so adding other
>   prevention methods can further reduce your risk.
>
> **How can I get the most protection from condoms?**
>
> It is best to read the label on the packaging the condom came in
>   before using the condom.
>
> Choose the right kind of condoms to prevent disease.
>
> Store them in a cool, dry place. Storing condoms near heat (your back
>   pocket or glove compartment) can make them weaker and less effective.
>
> Remember to use a new condom every time you have sex.
>
> **How does a condom protect against sexually transmitted infection?**
>
> A condom acts as a barrier or wall to keep blood, or semen, or vaginal
>   fluids from passing from one person to the other during intercourse.
>   These fluids can harbor germs such as HIV and other sexually
>   transmitted infections.  If no condom is used, the germs can pass from
>   the infected partner to the uninfected partner.
>
> **How do I choose the right kind of condoms to prevent disease?**
>
> Always read the label. Look for two things:
>
> The condoms should be made of *latex*, or *polyurethane* condoms for
>   people sensitive or allergic to latex. Tests have shown that latex and
>   polyurethane condoms (including the female condom) can prevent the
>   passage of the HIV, hepatitis and herpes viruses. But **natural
>   (lambskin) condoms may not do this**.
>
> *The package should say that the condoms are to prevent disease.* If the package doesn't say anything about preventing disease, the condoms
>   may not provide the protection you want, even though they may be the
>   most expensive ones you can buy.
>
> Novelty condoms will not say anything about either disease prevention
>   or pregnancy prevention on the package. They are intended only for
>   sexual stimulation, not protection.
>
> Condoms which do not cover the entire penis are not labeled for
>   disease prevention and should not be used for this purpose. For proper
>   protection, a condom must unroll to cover the entire penis. This is
>   another good reason to read the label carefully. *(emphasis added)*

---

This is a pretty amazing website that provides links to **28 different STD Risk Calculators**: http://www.calculators.org/health/std-risk.php .

---

Here is a **quick, easy-to-read table** that tells you which sexually transmitted diseases you can contract depending on whether you have anal or vaginal intercourse and whether or not the 'penetrating' male uses a condom: https://smartsexresource.com/sites/default/files/Anal-Vaginal-Sex-Table-v3.png

The website also has tables for oral sex and other types of sex: https://smartsexresource.com/about-stis/know-your-chances-0

---

Here is a **Fact Sheet** from the United States Centers for Disease Control that gives a quick overview of STD prevalence in the U.S. for 2015:

[CDC Fact Sheet: Reported STDs in the United States](https://www.cdc.gov/nchhstp/newsroom/docs/factsheets/STD-Trends-508.pdf) (PDF) – Summary of trends and highlights of data from 2015 Surveillance

---

More info on [**STDs You Can Get While Wearing A Condom**](https://www.stdcheck.com/blog/stds-you-can-get-while-wearing-a-condom/) - Molluscum Contagiosum, Pubic Lice/Crabs, Syphilis, Genital herpes, and HPV (human papillomavirus).

---

The U.S. Center for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) offers a ***Condoms and STDs: Fact Sheet for Public Health Personnel***, which is slightly more technical than the public fact sheet, but most readers here will understand it and I like the detail it provides. [HTML version](https://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/latex.html) | [PDF version](https://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/docs/Condoms_and_STDS.pdf)

---

From the *Advocates for Youth* website, **Condom Effectiveness** provides well-referenced information about the efficacy of condom use for various STDs. [HTML version](http://www.advocatesforyouth.org/publications/publications-a-z/416-condom-effectiveness) | [PDF version](http://www.advocatesforyouth.org/storage/advfy/documents/fscondomeffectiveness2005.pdf)